# Component not loaded in angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript, routes

Basically the route /users is not working , when I enter there it brings the component AppComponent instead the UsersComponent.

Why the route /users does not load the correctly component?

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule }          from '@angular/forms';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { UsersComponent } from './users/users.component';
import { AppRouting } from './app-routing.component'

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    UsersComponent
  ], 
   imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRouting,
    FormsModule
    // other imports here
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
}
```

user.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-users',
  templateUrl: './users.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./users.component.css']
})
export class UsersComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

app-routing.component.ts

```
import { UsersComponent } from './users/users.component';

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {RouterModule,Routes} from '@angular/router';


const routes:Routes =[
    {path:'',redirectTo:'/', pathMatch:'full'},
    //{path:'appcomponent',component:AppComponent},
    { path: 'users',      component: UsersComponent }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports:[RouterModule],
})
export class AppRouting{


}
```

In the html code I just want to show this:

user.component.html

```
<p>
  users works!
</p>
```

Comment: What is navigating to the user component? Are you typing it in the URL? Or is there something that is activating it?

Comment: Navigating directly or with href

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: There is not... Actually both components are loaded... Appcomponent and userscomponent in /users i just want the users.component.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to provide `router-outlet` in the `AppComponent` template.

```
...
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
...
```

Comment: I have added it , and it doesnt load the component

Comment: In fact it is loaded but angular doesn't remove the app.component.html how can I do that

Comment: @arnoldssss UsersComponent is component other than page

Comment: ... im not sure what that means... I just want to go to /users and display user.component.html and not both components togeter

Comment: Because `UsersComponent` actually a child component. So you need to   create a common parent, which does not contain any other view. After that provide two routes and two components

Comment: Got it... That component could have header and footer

Comment: @arnoldssss The main one ?

Comment: And the other components the more funcionality thanks

Answer (score 4):

Ah. I now understand. If you want to display routed components to take up the full display area, you need to define your app.component.html to ONLY have the router outlet. No other elements.

I've done something similar whereby I have a component with a menu. I want to show some components without that menu, such as the login component.

I did it using multiple levels of router outlets.

**App Component**

I defined the root application component with only a router outlet. Then I route into that component when I want a component to appear without the menu.

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**Shell Component**

Then I defined a "shell" component with a second router outlet. Here is where I defined my menu. Anything I want to appear with the menu, I route to this router outlet.

```
<mh-menu></mh-menu>
<div class='container'>
   <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

**Routing Module**

The routes are then configured using the `children` property to define the routes that are routed into the ShellComponent.

That way none of the components need to know if the menu should be on or off. It's all determined by the route configuration.

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
  {
    path: '',
    component: ShellComponent,
    children: [
      { path: 'welcome', component: WelcomeComponent },
      { path: 'movies', component: MovieListComponent },
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'welcome', pathMatch: 'full' }
    ]
  },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent }
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
])
```

[image: Shows the area of the app router outlet]
Shows the area of the app router outlet.

[image: Shows the area of the shell router outlet]
Shows the area of the shell router outlet.